# How does 飄 + 然 compound to mean 'floating in the air'?

Tags: etymology

[*ABC Chinese–English Comprehensive Dictionary* (2003)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABC_Chinese%E2%80%93English_Dictionary). I can't access the ["slightly revised through July 2005" ed.](https://wenlin.com/abc%22)

[image]

Neither [飄 nor 然](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%A3%84%E7%84%B6) mean 'air'. One can drift or float in water, or mentally in one's mind.

Answer (score 1):

飄's  radical is 風 (wind), and 風 is created by the movent of air

然 is a word particle that indicates "like" (in the manner of)

飄然 = like floating (in the air)